# Displaying picture for my website

Tags: wordpress

This is an example of me sharing my website:

[image]

I have a favicon set up but I would like to add a picture for my website. For example when I share it or bookmark it - there is no image and instead there is blank space displaying. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you bookmark a page that has a favicon, it often doesn't add the favicon to the bookmark bar until after you click on it again to open the page with the bookmark. If you're wondering about other ways of forcing it to have an icon (for example, as a web-app added to a mobile homescreen, etc.), what you need is a JSON manifest. Here are a few resources on that: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-installable-web-apps-with-webapp-manifest-in-chrome-38-for-Android?hl=en ; https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen ; https://w3c.github.io/manifest/.